How to set width of a inner div to 100% of scrollable parent DIV?
I want to inner div gets all width of scrollable parent div, this is my sample code:
<div class="col-6 flex-column gap-8px overflow-x-scroll">

  <div class="d-flex w-100 p-3 border bg-warning rounded col-12">
    <span class="col-4 bg-info m-2">col 1</span>
    <span class="col-4 bg-info m-2">col 2</span>
    <span class="col-4 bg-info m-2">col 3</span>
    <span class="col-4 bg-info m-2">col 4</span>
  </div>

</div>

and the result:

How i can fix this ?

Please add the tag for whatever framework you're using (e.g. Bootstrap), and edit the question to include a [mcve]

why would you need an inner div at all then? The outer div's already a flexbox, now you're just adding pointless divs.

Please  add references for any css class. Is it a framework ? which is its name and version !

You have to need remove  unwanted inner div,
try this ,


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example m-0 border-0 bd-example-row">

    <!-- Example Code -->
    
    <div class="col-6 d-flex border bg-warning rounded  gap-8px overflow-x-scroll">
        <span class="col bg-info m-2 text-center">col 1</span>
        <span class="col bg-info m-2 text-center">col 2</span>
        <span class="col bg-info m-2 text-center">col 3</span>
        <span class="col bg-info m-2 text-center">col 4</span>
    </div>



link  ---> https://jsfiddle.net/uke1jos9/

The problem is caused by using two wrappers instead of one, as per the hint from @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans.


.bg-pink {
  overflow: auto;
  background: pink;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.bg-gold {
  background: gold;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.d1 {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 3px solid red;
  background: gold;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

span {
  background: cyan;
  width: 30%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
<p>Scroll the panels below to the right.</p>
<p>This example is based on your HTML structure. As you scroll right, the gold background does not extend the full width. You'll also note that there is no padding between column 4 and the red border.</p>
<div class="bg-pink">
  <div class="bg-gold">
    <span>col 1</span>
    <span>col 2</span>
    <span>col 3</span>
    <span>col 4</span>
  </div>
</div>


<p>Both the above problems result from using two wrapper elements instead of one. The solution is to combine them.</p>
<div class="d1">
  <span>col 1</span>
  <span>col 2</span>
  <span>col 3</span>
  <span>col 4</span>
</div>



